# CKAN resource file upload by api?

Tags: api, ckan

How do I upload file in to resource (either create or update)in CKAN using apis.

I followed the documentation it seems working but getting an error at datapusher page.

[Click here for Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCfEc.png)

Answer (score 2):

> this error indicates a time-out when the datapusher service tries to download the resource from CKAN.

@florianm is dead right here.

Another thing to check is the resource url. The exception suggests you've forgotten to put `http://` on the front of the url, or something similar.

Also note that you can [upload files directly to CKAN](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/filestore.html) if they are not already on-line somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

@Vithal this error indicates a time-out when the datapusher service tries to download the resource from CKAN.

Some pointers:

- What do your CKAN and datapusher error logs say?
- How big is your resource file?
- Does this error occur when you upload a tiny CSV file?
- Does this error occur when you upload your original resource file to 
  demo.ckan.org?